# How to print json object property values?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object like this:

```
JsonQuery = ​'{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 200,
    "sort": [{
        "Modified": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                    "CollectionId": {
                        "value": "abcd"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "terms": {
                    "Container": ["en-us"]
                }
            }],
            "must_not": [{
                "wildcard": {
                    "_type": {
                        "value": "@@"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "DynamicProperties.MainSpec"
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "DynamicProperties.ExtendedSpec"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}';
```

I am creating a javascript object by doing

```
var obj = JSON.parse(JsonQuery);
```

I go in chrome console and I write `obj` and hit enter and it displays the object properly but when I try to access the property of the object, it keeps saying undefined.
For example: I am using `obj.size`.

Answer (score 2):

You only have a gremlin on your first line (JsonQuery = '), try to remove it and retry.

```js
jsonQuery = '{"from":0,"size":200,"sort":[{"Modified":{"order":"desc"}}],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"CollectionId":{"value":"abcd"}}},{"terms":{"Container":["en-us"]}}],"must_not":[{"wildcard":{"_type":{"value":"@@"}}},{"bool":{"filter":{"exists":{"field":"DynamicProperties.MainSpec"}},"filter":{"exists":{"field":"DynamicProperties.ExtendedSpec"}}}}]}}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonQuery);

console.log(obj.size);
```